# Combine 3 Wordpress Templates into one by passing the args value into the url

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates

I have written an archive template which outputs the custom post type artists into the page. I had to introduce a filter which organizes artists into orders. There three orders were All('orderby' => 'rand') Newest('orderby'=> 'post_date') and ALPHABETICAL('orderby' => 'title'). What method i adpoted was i created 3 templates and changed the orderby parameter accordingly which made 3 different templates for three different filter categories. The whole code for each template is below with the only exception of orderby which is changing according to the template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Aritsts
*/


$args = array(

        'category'         => $id,

        'post_type'      => 'artists',

        'post_status'    => 'publish',

        'orderby'        => 'rand',

        'order'          => 'ASC',

        );



get_header(); ?>



<div id="content" style="width:100%">
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="post-content">
<article id="content-items">
<div id="filter-artist">
<span>FILTER:</span> 
<?php
echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists" class="active-filter">ALL</a>';
echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists-newest"  >NEWEST</a>';
echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists-alphabetical" >ALPHABETICAL</a>';
?>
</div>
<div id="load-items">


<?php

 $query = new WP_Query($args  );


     if ( $query -> have_posts()) {

     while ($query->have_posts())   
     { 
            $query->the_post();

            $post_title = get_the_title( get_the_ID()  );

            $post_facebook_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'artist_facebook_url', true );

            $post_twitter_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'artist_twitter_url', true);

            $post_instagram_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'artist_instagram_url', true);

            $post_website_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'artist_website_url', true);

            $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'medium' ); 
            $post_default =  get_site_url() 
        ?>

            <div class="artist">

            <div class="thumb-artist">

            <?php 

            if(!$post_thumbnail)
                {
                    echo '<img width="165" height="110" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/no-photo.jpg" class="attachment-220x110 wp-post-image" />'; 
                }
                else
                {
                    echo  $post_thumbnail ; 
                }
                ?>


           <span class="social-content">

          <a href= <?php if(!$post_facebook_url){echo site_url();} else{echo $post_facebook_url;}?>  target="_blank" <?php if(!$post_facebook_url){echo 'style="display:none;"';} else{echo 'class="facebook social"';} ?> >&nbsp;</a>
          <a href= <?php if(!$post_twitter_url){echo site_url();} else{echo $post_twitter_url;}?>  target="_blank" <?php if(!$post_twitter_url){echo 'style="display:none;"';} else{echo 'class="twitter social"';} ?> >&nbsp;</a>
          <a href= <?php if(!$post_instagram_url){echo site_url();} else{echo $post_instagram_url;}?>  target="_blank" <?php if(!$post_instagram_url){echo 'style="display:none;"';} else{echo 'class="instagram social"';} ?> >&nbsp;</a>
          <a href= <?php if(!$post_website_url){echo site_url();} else{echo $post_website_url;}?>  target="_blank" <?php if(!$post_website_url){echo 'style="display:none;"';} else{echo 'class="web social sat-color"';} ?> >&nbsp;</a>



            </span>

            </div>

           <h3 class="name-artist"><?php  echo $post_title;   ?></h3>

            </div>



<?php  } } else { echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' ); } ?>

</div></article></div></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What i want to achieve is to combine these 3 templates into one template by creating three different args and pass them into the url and update the url value here :

```
<?php

echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists">ALL</a>';

echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists-newest" >NEWEST</a>';

echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists-alphabetical" class="active-filter">ALPHABETICAL</a>';

?>
```

I am a rookie at php so please dont judge me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use just one template with different queries, either way here is a solution:

Change your query to this

```
$args = array(

        'category'         => $id,

        'post_type'      => 'artists',

        'post_status'    => 'publish',

        'orderby'        => ($_GET["orderby"]),

        'order'          => ($_GET["order"]),

        );
```

Then you can use URLs in your links like:
`<a href="'.get_site_url().'/artists-alphabetical?orderby=title&order=ASC" >ALPHABETICAL</a>`

The `$_Get` receives a variable from the URL and passes it into your query.